# Trading Indicator needs refurnishing

Tags: background-color, trading, indicator

I'm a newcomer here, so please bear with me 
I'm experiencing a problem with a script I'm working on. I've revamped a Bull & Bear indicator and plan to publish it on TradingView as soon as I resolve the issue.

In the SETTINGS section, under STYLE, I have three distinct VOID BACKGROUND COLOR options available to utilize in the indicator.

For some reason, there are four background colors associated with each VOID option, but only one of them is actually utilized and visible within the indicator. I intend to remove the three unused background colors, but I'm unable to locate them in the code.

[the problem is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4yCz.png)

[as well as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8hFR.png)

```
I will write part of the code here:

var color StrongBullArea = color.new(color.green, 55) // Define Strong Bull Area
var color WeakBullArea = color.new(color.green, 70)  // Define Weak Bull Area
var color SlowingBullArea = color.new(color.green, 85) // Define Slowing Bull Area

var color StrongBearArea = color.new(color.red, 55)   // Define Strong Bear Area
var color WeakBearArea = color.new(color.red, 70)     // Define Weak Bear Area
var color SlowingBearArea = color.new(color.red, 85)  // Define Slowing Bear Area

var color voidColor = na

// VOLUME VOID SETTINGS
var string volumeVoidFunction = input.string("Relative Volume Comparison", title="Volume Void Function",   
options=["Relative Volume Comparison", "Percentage of Average Volume", "Fixed Volume Threshold",   
"Volatility-   
Adjusted Volume", "Compare to Previous Volume Bars", "Volume Percentile Rank", "Market Session Comparison"])
var float voidBullSensitivity = input.float(5, title="Void Bull Sensitivity", step=0.1)
var float voidBearSensitivity = input.float(5, title="Void Bear Sensitivity", step=0.1)
var float bullPowerPeak = na
var float bearPowerPeak = na

// VOID FUNCTION SETTINGS
var lowVolumeBars = input.int(3, title="Number of Previous Bars", tooltip="Defines the number of previous   
bars    
to consider when calculating the average volume in the 'Compare to Previous Volume Bars' function.")
var lookbackPeriod = input.int(50, title="Lookback Period", tooltip="Defines the period over which the   
percentile rank of the current volume is calculated in the 'Volume Percentile Rank' function.") 
var lowVolumePercentile = input.float(25, title="Low Volume Percentile", tooltip="Defines the percentile      
threshold below which the volume is considered low in the 'Volume Percentile Rank' function.")

// Define Volume Void Logic
var bool lowVolumeCondition = na
var bool strongStartCondition = na
var bool continuationCondition = na

// Volume Void Logic for different options
if volumeVoidFunction == "Relative Volume Comparison"
lowVolumeCondition := volume > ta.sma(volume, 50) * voidBearSensitivity
strongStartCondition := ta.sma(volume, 50) > volume * voidBullSensitivity
continuationCondition := lowVolumeCondition

if volumeVoidFunction == "Percentage of Average Volume"
averageVolume = ta.sma(volume, 50)
lowVolumeCondition := volume > averageVolume * voidBearSensitivity
strongStartCondition := averageVolume > volume * voidBullSensitivity
continuationCondition := lowVolumeCondition

if volumeVoidFunction == "Fixed Volume Threshold"
lowVolumeCondition := volume > voidBearSensitivity
strongStartCondition := volume < voidBullSensitivity
continuationCondition := lowVolumeCondition

if volumeVoidFunction == "Volatility-Adjusted Volume"
atrValue = ta.atr(14)
lowVolumeCondition := volume > atrValue * voidBearSensitivity
strongStartCondition := volume < atrValue * voidBullSensitivity
continuationCondition := lowVolumeCondition

if volumeVoidFunction == "Compare to Previous Volume Bars"
lowVolumeCondition := volume > ta.sma(volume, lowVolumeBars) * voidBearSensitivity
strongStartCondition := volume < ta.sma(volume, lowVolumeBars) * voidBullSensitivity
continuationCondition := lowVolumeCondition

if volumeVoidFunction == "Volume Percentile Rank"
volumePercentile = ta.percentrank(volume, lookbackPeriod)
lowVolumeCondition := volumePercentile > lowVolumePercentile
continuationCondition := lowVolumeCondition

// Void Color Background Conditions
var float startBullVolume = na
var float startBearVolume = na

if (bullPower > voidBullSensitivity)
if (na(startBullVolume))
startBullVolume := volume
if (volume < startBullVolume)
voidColor := na
startBullVolume := na
bullPowerPeak := na

else
if (na(bullPowerPeak) or bullPower > bullPowerPeak)
bullPowerPeak := bullPower
if (bullPower < bullPowerPeak * 0.9)
voidColor := SlowingBullArea
else
voidColor := StrongBullArea

else if (bearPower < -voidBearSensitivity)
if (na(startBearVolume))
startBearVolume := volume
if (volume > startBearVolume)
voidColor := na
startBearVolume := na
bearPowerPeak := na

else
if (na(bearPowerPeak) or bearPower < bearPowerPeak)
bearPowerPeak := bearPower
if (bearPower > bearPowerPeak * 0.9)
voidColor := SlowingBearArea
else
voidColor := StrongBearArea

else
voidColor := na
startBullVolume := na
startBearVolume := na

bgcolor(voidColor == StrongBullArea ? StrongBullArea : na, title="Strong Bull Area")
bgcolor(voidColor == SlowingBullArea ? SlowingBullArea : na, title="Slowing Bull Area")
bgcolor(voidColor == WeakBullArea ? WeakBullArea : na, title="Weak Bull Area")
bgcolor(voidColor == StrongBearArea ? StrongBearArea : na, title="Strong Bear Area")
bgcolor(voidColor == SlowingBearArea ? SlowingBearArea : na, title="Slowing Bear Area")
bgcolor(voidColor == WeakBearArea ? WeakBearArea : na, title="Weak Bear Area")
```

I dont know, its been a mess.